# jms serializer same entity relation

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have an entity with a manyToOne relation on the same entity

```
class Post {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Post::class, mappedBy="lotParent")
     */
    private $linkedPosts;
}
```

How can I serialize all my posts properties for the main post without serializing all the properties of the children ?

my yaml serialisation file is like this but all the propoerties are visible for the children :

```
App\Entity\Post:
    ExclusionPolicy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
            groups: [viewPost, viewChildPost]
        title:
            expose: true
            groups: [viewPost]
        ......
        linkedPosts:
            expose: true
            groups: [viewChildPost]
```

I don't want the children title in this example.
Can I use symfony expressions on serialization groups ? I didn't saw something like this

Comment: Putting the `viewChildPost` group on `linkedPosts` doesn't tell JMS to ignore the `viewPost` group whenever it serializes the contents of this property. It will still apply `viewPost` when serializing these "child" posts (assuming both are active).

I believe what you need is a custom [dynamic exclusion strategy](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#dynamic-exclusion-strategy). One that logically excludes the `title` property when dealing with "child" posts.

Comment: Yes, but what expression can I write ? this is the problem. I can't see something to write a rule on a serialisation group